# New names: * `` -> `..18` message in R console

Tags: r, readxl

I ran a Rshiny app and it works as expected but in console I get the following message:

```
New names:
* `` -> `..18`
```

what does it mean?

It occurs when I try to do this

```
> data1<-read_excel("CUMMULATIVE COLLECTION POS_UPLOAD.xls")
New names:
* `` -> `..18`
```

When I do the same operation again it doesn't gives the message

```
> data2<-read_excel("DATA.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The message is telling you that some of the columns have no names and its giving them one. The second excel simply must have all the column names defined.
It also appears to me since the last update of the readxl package.
Worth noting that the format of the created names have change, wich force me to charge previous codes.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress these messages?

Comment: I guess with suppressWarnings, but havent try it.

Answer (score 7):

add this argument `.name_repair = "unique_quiet"` to the `read_excel` function, and it will do it.